# Conditional PDF of X, given random variable Y based on the PDF of X

Tags: probability, random-variables

X is a random variable with PDF: $F_X(x)=\frac{1}{2}sin(x)$ on the interval $[0,\pi]$
If $X\in[0,\frac{\pi}{3}],Y=3$
If $X\in(\frac{\pi}{3},\frac{2\pi}{3}],Y=2$
If $X\in(\frac{2\pi}{3},\pi],Y=1$
What is the conditional probability density function of X given Y =2?
$f_{X|Y}(x|Y=2)=?$
I tried starting by calculating $P(Y=2)$, but could not figure out how to do that from the way thay Y is defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $F_X$ is a *probability density function* (not CDF as is usually indicated by use of capital lettering): $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(Y{=}2)~&=~\mathsf P(\tfrac\pi 3{\lt} X{\leqslant}\tfrac{2\pi}{3})\\[1ex]&=~\int_{\pi/3}^{2\pi/3} F_X(x)~\mathrm d x\end{align}$$And so using Bayes' Rule: $$F_X(x\mid Y{=}2)=\dfrac{F_X(x)\mathbf 1_{\pi/3<x\leqslant 2\pi/3}}{\mathsf P(Y=2)}$$

Comment: Sorry, I can't see how I would solve for the PDF with Bayes' Rule if I do not know $P(Y=2)$.  Would you mind adding that to the answer?

Comment: It *is* in the answer.

Comment: Sorry, but isn't the question specifically asking for the conditional PDF? I don't think I can leave it in terms of $P(Y=2)$

Comment: Thank you for the edit. Though the added bold feels a tad passive aggressive.

Comment: Hi, I am so sorry, I just noticed in the question that I had written Y = 2 for the last one as well, it was supposed to be Y =1. I have made the adjustment. I also submitted an edit to your answer, but it has to be approved. 
Sadly, I am now confused, as $P(\frac{2\pi}{3}) = P(\frac{\pi}{3})$ so $P(Y=2) =0...$

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this answer is incorrect, as your definition for P(Y=2) does not work.

Comment: Ah, @Shawn , I see now that your function $F_X$ is a pdf, rather than a CDF (as is usually indicated by capital F). $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(Y=2) &= \int_{\pi/3}^{2\pi/3}(1/2)\sin(x)~\mathrm d x\\& = \tfrac 12\end{align} $$

Comment: It looks like there is an error in the formatting of the last line, would you be able to fix that? I am unsure of what it means with the bolded 1, and subscript inequality

Comment: That is an Indicator function: valued as 1 when the indicated condition is satisfied, but valued as 0 otherwise. $$\mathbf 1_{x\in(a:b]}=\begin{cases}1&:&a<x\leq b\\0&:&\text{elsewhere}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Would there be a way to solve this without the indicator function? We have not covered that yet in my class.

Comment: It is just a statement of the support for the function (the interval for the argument where the function is non-zero).$$F_X(x\mid Y{=}2)~=~\begin{cases}\left.F_X(x)\middle/\mathsf P\bigl(\pi/3<x\leq 2\pi/3\bigr)\right.  &:& \pi/3<x\leq 2\pi/3\\[1ex]0&:&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$